# can I have a return value from Eval() method in a databound Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Please refer to the code below. The template field is a part of a gridview. I have a requirement where I want to pass the string from Boundfield "TriggerEvent" to a method "Alert()" that should do some operation on the string and display it back in the grid. I have encountered error in this which is explainable. How do I achieve this functionality?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TriggerEvent" SortExpression="TriggerEvent" ItemStyle-    Wrap="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Alert(Eval("TriggerEvent")) %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: How and where is `Alert` declared? Also, what is the error?

Comment: Do your processing before the binding. During the binding  you should only do simple formatting things. No logical computations.

Comment: @Candide, problem with pre-processing is, its a huge dataset and the processing is sequential if I access the datafields by each "DataRow" and putting the updated value back to dataset to be bound eventually. I was looking for some parallel operation that should do preprocessing of that particular column in all rows at once. Thanks though !

Comment: @Andrei, error is because Eval() doesnt "return" a string that is input to my Alert() method. Alert is declared centrally, available everywhere as a common utility.

Comment: @ShwetaSaxena, Eval does not return string indeed, it returns object. And there is no such thing as globally declared method in C#, it has to be a part of some class

Comment: @Andrei ,its just declared at mycompanyname.commonutility.Alert() which happens to be the common namespace included everywhere and the method is static. the error is that Alert() best overloaded match is not met because Eval() doesnot return string.

Comment: Point is , is it not possible to do what I am trying to do, or is there any other efficient way to do it faster, because huge dataset taking too much preprocessing time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eval is returning object and Alert is expecting string, you can cast is with `as`:

```
Text='<%# Alert(Eval("TriggerEvent") as string) %>'
```

Comment: This gives me a Compile Exception " The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context"}, Is it because I am doing :                                  Text='<%# Alert(Bind("TriggerEvent") as string) %>' too?

Comment: @ShwetaSaxena, you definitely need to make sure you put all details in the question right away. `Eval` and `Bind` are very-very different things. `Eval` is a simple function, and `Bind` is a special construct that enables two-way data binding. The one and only way to use `Bind` is `<%# Bind("TriggerEvent") %>`, you cannot call functions on it or cast result to something - ASP.NET simply won't recognize it in any other form

Comment: how do I bind this updated value to gridview then? the solution, results in blank gridview.. My purpose is to update the "TriggerEvent" value and display that in gridview.

Comment: @ShwetaSaxena, how do you want to update it? If the grid view, than you need to refrain from using any other function around Bind. If you just want to display it in grid view and update elsewhere, than eval should suffice